# SQL: Select all rows that match something in another table

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to write a query like this (hopefully with only one Query):
Select all messages from inbox table where the "SenderNumber" of the message is found in "Sentitems" table and the CreatorID is 'Martin'

For example my **inbox** table looks like this:

```
| SenderNumber   |   TextMessage    |
    11111111       Yes, nice world!
    22222222         Howdy folks!
```

And my **sentitems** table looks very similar

```
| DestinationNumber  | TextMessage |  CreatorID
      11111111         Hello world?    Martin
      22222222          How you do?     John
```

I would like to get all message from Inbox table with this condition - there is an entry for this *"SenderNumber" / "DestinationNumber"* in my **sentitems** table and the **CreatorID** is 'Martin'.

So in this case it would return this entry because the creatorID for the other number is not 'Martin' but 'John'

```
| SenderNumber   |   TextMessage    |
    11111111       Yes, nice world!
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Have you ever tried to work with a `JOIN`? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647941/select-rows-where-a-value-matches-another-value-in-another-table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one :

```
SELECT i.SenderNumber, i.TextMessage
FROM inbox as i
INNER JOIN sentitems as s ON s.DestinationNumber = i.SenderNumber AND s.CreatorID = 'Martin'
```

The logic is :

1. You select what you want, here `SenderNumber` and `TextMessage` from the table `inbox`
2. Now you use an `INNER JOIN` with the table `sentitems` and two conditions : `DestinationNumber` from table `sentitems` and `SenderNumber` from table `inbox` are the same + `CreatorID` with the value you want, here 'Martin'

Using `INNER JOIN` will return only the result that respect the two conditions. For more information, take a look to the documentation : https://sql.sh/cours/jointures/inner-join

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!